# Retrieve PID of process by path, not name, with multiple users

Tags: vbscript, path, admin, pid

I'm trying to retrieve the PID of all the instances of a software in a specific location. It's a portable app, so there may be multiple copies of it across the system, but I'm interested in one specific location only. Also, it can be startes by different users simultaneously, admins as well standard users.

I copied this VBS code (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'foobar.exe'")

For Each objProcess in colProcesses
    If objProcess.GetOwner(User, Domain) = 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "Process " & objProcess.Name & " belongs to " & Domain & "\" & User
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Problem " & Rtn & " getting the owner for process " & objProcess.Caption
    End If
Next
```

I now need to distinguish the full path of the app. If I use `objProcess.ExecutablePath` (5th line) I can see the full path of the instances launched **by the current user only**, while using `Where ExecutablePath` (3rd line) gives some sort of syntax error.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you'll need admin privileges (more specifically [`SeDebugPrivilege`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/03/14/8080140.aspx)) to see processes of other users.

The syntax error you get when using a `Where ExecutablePath = '...'` clause is probably because you didn't escape backslashes in the path. Backslashes in WMI queries [escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms696030%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) characters with special meaning, so you need to double them to get literal backslashes:

```
Select * From Win32_Process Where ExecutablePath = 'C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe'
```

I'm merely guessing here, though, since you decided to omit both the actual query with the Where clause and the error it raised.